# How do I move an RLMObject up in the RLMResults

Tags: realm

I have RLMObjects representing Countries. I use `allObjects` to get them, followed by `sortedResultsUsingProperty:` to make them A-Z but I want to have the USA Country at the top of the list (index 0).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own sorting criteria in that case, or, more likely, create an RLMResults that filters out your USA country object and handle it separately.